# Avoiding contract impersonation

Tags: solidity, security

Newbie question. Suppose I have contract X which have a foo function which accepts contract of type Y and calls function bar on it like this.

```
contract Y
{
 function bar() public;
}

contract X
{
 function foo(Y y) public { y.bar(); } 
}
```

If my understanding is correct then anyone can write contract Z with the same ABI as Y and pass it as a parameter to the contract X's foo function (impersonate Y). If that is correct, is it possible to ensure that only "trusted" contracts are passed as a parameter to the X::foo.

Comment: Do you expect to have a single Y instance or to have many of them?

Comment: @Ismael many of them. But i need to mark which of  them are trusted. Currently the only way I found is hard coding the trusted owner id. an comparing it in  each 
 call to msg.sender

Comment: If X has a single instance one option is to require every valid Y to register with X by X's owner. If there are many instances of X a separate registry like contract may work. It is hard to recommend something that will work well for every situation.